# How to format a float number to the right in C?

Tags: c, string-formatting

I'd like to print a float number with only 2 decimal places and align it to the right in a 6 characters space.

I tried to do this, but didn't work:

```
printf("%6.2f", value);
```

Comment: What *did* it do and how *didn't* it work? That right-aligns a 6-char output, including decimal point, with two places filled on the right. `printf("%6.2f",1.0)` gives `"  1.00"` for example. What *exactly* do you want the output to be, and with what input do you want it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you've posted will fit the whole float into a 6 char wide column with the .xx taking up the last 3. If you want the integer portion in a six char wide column with the '.' and the fractional portion after these 6 characters, its %9.2f. Quick example program to show the differences

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  float x = 83.4;
  printf("....|....|....|\n");
  printf("%6.2f\n", x); // prints " 83.40"
  printf("%9.2f\n", x); // prints "    83.40"

  return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
....|....|....|
 83.40
    83.40
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put - after %

```
printf("%-6.2f", value);
```